# What do you call a chart that illustrates class hierarchy?

Tags: oop, uml

So I have a UML type chart that documents the classes and the hierarchy of a development. Just don't know what you'd call it?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What you mean by the hierarchy of a developement? You mean inheritance of the class?

Answer (score 8):

[Class diagram](http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/2206791) is a nice start ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Static Structure is another name for that entire suite of diagrams.